# stop cursor blinking on web page

Tags: html

When I click on web page the cursor start blinking and adjust its height according to table size. I want to stop that blinking. Is there any solution?

Comment: You mean the text cursor? I doubt very much you can do anything about that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there is no way to influence the blinking behaviour of the text cursor. This is entirely up to the browser and the operating system.

Here is a (very kludgy IMO) approach to hiding the text cursor altogether: [Hide textfield blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)

Answer (score 14):

Here’s the correct answer if not late though, It’s called caret browsing hit F7 to turn off simple as that

Comment: Could you add a source for reference?

Comment: Brilliant!  That blinking cursor was bugging me and I assumed it was due to a recent Chrome update, so it's good to know it's as simple as an F7.

Comment: Wow, I've been stuck at this for days now. They should put a mark on the screen so we know something is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Wow i didn't know this, it's been really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

May be you have turned on your Caret Browsing, press f7 to get rid of it