# Prevent browser from displaying text selector on input focus

Tags: html, css, input

is it possible to prevent web browsers from displaying the text selector (the "|" which alternatively shows and hides) when an input is focused?

Comment: You want to hide the blinking cursor, or the textarea:hover,input[type="text"]:hover{cursor:text;} thing?

Comment: The blinking "|" is called a caret.

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? That would be a great way to hamper site usability.

Comment: Duplicate of [Hide textfield blinking cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set css property that will work in every browsers.

However there is a one solution that i kept in mind.

Read this article its explained well there -> http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html