# how to hide blinking caret in input text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make something which would look like a select input but is actually not, here are the steps.

I made an `<input type="text">`.

I added a `background-image`, which will show a "select arrow", giving the impression that it's a select box.

I added a default value to this input.

There will be a hidden div which will `SlideDown()` right under this input when I click on it.

I tried the read only thing so that the value cannot be changed, but the blinking caret will show up.

If I use `disabled`, the blinking caret will not show up, but the `.click()` or `.focus` function will not work. The drop down menu will not `SlideDown()`.

How can I make it clickable while not showing the blinking caret?

Here's the code

```
<div style="padding-top:17px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="secretquestion">Secret Question</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="inputselect" id="secretquestion" name="secretquestion" value="Choose a Secret Question" tabindex=10 /><br>
        <div class="selectoptions" id="secretquestionoptions">
            <b>test</b>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.selectoptions
{
    display: none;
    background-color: white;  
    color: rgb(46,97,158); 
    width: 250px; 
    margin:auto; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-color: rgb(46,97,158);  
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.inputselect {
    color: white;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    background-image: url('inputselect.png');
    padding-top: 5px; 
    padding-bottom: 5px;   
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:-10px;
    width:240px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: rgb(46,97,158); 
    border-width: 1px;
} 
.inputselect:hover {
    outline:none;      
    color:aqua; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    background-image: url('inputselecthover.png');
}
.inputselect:focus {
    outline:none;      
    color:aqua; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    background-image: url('inputselecthover.png');
}
```

Comment: [A possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor).

Another solution is to use a div styled to look like an input instead of an actual input.

Comment: @JimmyX yes i thought about that but the thing is, this input (select) is in a form, the input fields all look like each other, and i dont feel like breaking the rule, and design another div with a fake look :P

Comment: ...which takes us back to the first solution (link): create an invisible input on top of the display input, then connect the two with some js.

Comment: I think you will find that the only way to do this is to not use an input field.  The behaviors of the form fields are controlled by the  browser, they aren't configurable.  The only other thing I can think of is to set the focus someplace else, and that will cause other issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide textfield blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)

Answer (score 169):

Just add this to "inputselect" class:

```
caret-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Did you check the browser support for this ? I can confirm this works in Firefox75

Comment: It's supported in most modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=caret-color.

Comment: All the answers I found so far were hinting at cursor: none while the correct attribute is caret-color.

Answer (score 65):

The color of the cursor matches the color of the text.

```
<input type="text" style="color: transparent">
```

If you actually want to show text in the input box (my, some people are needy), you can use a text shadow.

```
<style>
    body, div, input {
       color: #afa;
       text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    }
<style>
```

(tested Firefox and Safari).

Comment: Wow! What a brilliant idea! It is also possible to write `text-shadow: 0 0 0 #fff;` - that gives the same sharp text at the same position of the original.

Comment: Does not appear to work on IE 10 http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/mk77W/ black blinking cursor is still shown.

Comment: Sorry, IE what now?  I use a Mac.

Comment: I have no idea to deal with text's color, thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

I just used a blur to get rid of the cursor.

```
$('input').mousedown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).blur();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't want anybody to be able to type.  He said he tried "readonly" but the cursor still appeared. He's just using an input for the sake of keyboard navigation I guess, but wants it to behave like a select box.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a perfect solution: make the input wide enough, align right to screen right, thus make cursor and content locate at the outside of the screen, while it's still clickable

[image: perfect solution]

Answer (score 2):

try this code it worked on me :-

```
<div class="input-parent" style="margin-left: 30px;">
     <input type="text" />
</div>


input-parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.input-parent input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    text-align: left;
    caret-color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally find a trick solution.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

.wrappr {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

and in my sitation, it works!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
input {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #2196f3;

  &:focus {
      outline: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful (though not a complete response) - I used it to disable input in a recent project:

```
document.getElementById('Object').readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById('Object').style.backgroundColor = '#e6e6e6';
    document.getElementById('Object').onfocus = function(){
        document.getElementById('Object').blur();
    };
```

The user focuses on the input when the click in it, the blur() function then removes the focus. Between this, setting the readOnly to "True" and setting the background color to grey (#e6e6e6), your user shouldn't get confused.