# cursor position does not appear in text input?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

In my asp.net MVC app, I'm using a HTML text input, while I apply a style to format currecy value and I want it to RIGHT align so that I also apply style.

But the cursor does not appear in text box? What is the possible reason and please provide the solution?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="OnlyMoney" />
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("input[type=text].OnlyMoney").live('keydown', currenciesOnly)
           .live('blur',
           function() { $(this).formatCurrency(); });

   });
```

**CSS**

```
.OnlyMoney { text-align: right; }
```

**Note:** If I change above style "text-align: left" then cursor is visible in text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced a similar issue and adding `padding` solved my problem. Just give some padding right to your `.OnlyMoney` class and check

**CSS:**

```
 .OnlyMoney { text-align: right; padding: 0 2px 0 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59772993/1769274). this solved my issue.

Just style your input like this:

```
caret-color: #333333;
```