# Is there a way to style/hide the index line in HTML inputs?

Tags: html, css, input

In HTML inputs, there is the line that indicates where you type right now:

[image: The line I'm talking about.]

I wanted to know whether is there a way to style it, or at least hide it?

Thanks.

Comment: This link should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333044/how-to-hide-blinking-cursor-in-input-text

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on this post: [Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Be very careful about styling/removing the text Caret, it is usually controlled by the browser and not editable with CSS for good reason. Users need it to understand where they are typing and are not accustomed to see it styled strangely.