# Replace blinking text cursor with custom char

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating something like MySQL cmd and to have complete design, I want to replace insertion point (that blinking line) with underline sing. Any tips?

Comment: I believe this is OS's stuff not browser side...which means you cannot. I guess you could fake it with javascript though.

Comment: i don't see the need to downvote just because you don't know how to do it. Or even it can't be done. I myself wanted to do this once.

Comment: maybe you will need to know difference between these Lol..
`clientheight` vs `offsetheight` vs `scrollheight` vs `innerheight` vs `outerheight` vs `style.height` vs `getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were hoping this would be easy, the bad news is that there simply isn't a quick and simple way to do this -- the text cursor is not something you can just change with a couple of lines of javascript or CSS.

If you really want to do this, you're going to need to write your own entire text input system in javascript -- display the cursor yourself, wait for key presses, print them to the screen, handle anything like word-wrapping manually.... it's a fair bit of work.

Fortunately, others have already done this work and made it available to share, so I suggest your best starting point would be to take a look at some existing examples and see how they've done it.

Here's one I found with a quick bit of googling: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/. There are plenty of others you could try as well though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?17450-Emulating-a-terminal-like-caret-with-javascript-and-css and this: http://www.masswerk.at/jsuix/index.html and I'm trying to use it but I'm newbie in javascript so it will take plenty of time to understand it:D. Thx for tips.

Comment: You can only change the cursor color. Via `caret-color` CSS, but that's about it :((

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do.

- Make input text field invisible, so usable but invisible.
- copy its content
- render it to another div.
- and and add a custom box or whatever...

[Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

[Hide textfield blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)

Comment: Linked references were very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
textarea{
   cursor:url(underlineimage.png),auto;
}
```

Replace textarea with whatever element you want the cursor to be changed on. You will need to create a custom image of what you want your cursor to look like.

Comment: Ah, seems I did misunderstand the question.