# Can the text cursor be accessed from the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom, cursor

I am wondering if it is possible to access the [text cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28computers%29#Text_cursor) of an `<input type="text">`.

Does it have a specific node in the DOM?

My initial feeling is that this is OS-specific, but if any one knows of a way to access it via JS / jQuery / CSS / XSLT then please let me know (non-cross-browser inclusive).

Purposes for this could include changing its colour, thickness, blink rate, perhaps even substituting it for a custom cursor like a DOS-esque underscore, a .gif animation, anything other than the ubiquitous 1px [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Computing)!

Comment: Yes, there are multiple answers that you could've used. Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138762/replace-blinking-text-cursor-with-custom-char

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered before on this site. See the link below for more information.

It talks about simulating the caret with javascript and it looks like that might be the best bet.

[Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)