# How to hide blinking cursor from HTML text input in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text input that i want to hide it's blinking cursor.

I found a solution (setting color to transparent) that working fine in FireFox and Chrome
but this solution didn't work in IE.

Is there a solution for this?

```
<input type="text" value="dummydummydummy" tabindex="-1" id='test' style="cursor: none;color: transparent; width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color:transparent; border:solid transparent 1px; outline: none; position: absolute; z-index: 2000"/>
```

Also I **don't** want to blur the control immediately after input gets focus. because I need the control to be focused.

**note : I am testing this in IE8**

Comment: :( that is my required browser to implement this :(

Comment: Check out http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?17450-Emulating-a-terminal-like-caret-with-javascript-and-css

Comment: Have you seen this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor

Comment: @Richard : textarea doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: add `text-transform: capitalize;` to the styles and see!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a button to make that textfield focusable (with blink) or not.

With JQuery:

```
$('#test').on("focus",blurMe);
var focusable = false;

function blurMe(){
    $(this).blur();
}

$('#swapper').click(function(){
    if(focusable){
        $('#test').on("focus",blurMe);
        focusable = false;
    }else{
        $('#test').off("focus",blurMe);
        focusable = true;
    }   
});
```

And html :

```
<input type="text" value="dummydummydummy" tabindex="-1" id='test' style="cursor: none;color: transparent; width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color:transparent; border:solid transparent 1px; outline: none; position: absolute; z-index: 2000"/>
<input type="button" id="swapper">
```