# How to remove the caret from an input element

Tags: html, css, input

How can I remove the caret from a  `<input type="text">` element only using CSS and not JavaScript?

Comment: What are you referring for? Can you attach an image?

Comment: You mean the insertion point cursor (caret)? Why would you want to remove it?

Comment: If anyone still looking for an answer.  caret-color:"transparent",cursor:"default and if you are using react, onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(0 }}  will disable the edit

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Of course you can do it just with `CSS`.

Add this code to your CSS file:

```
border: none;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 0 gray;
text-align: center;

&:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Here you have the [SOURCE](https://coderwall.com/p/tsbmfw) and a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KvdkV/)

Comment: Not working in IE

Comment: All I had found were awful hacks done with javascript and two input fields. Thanks so much for this solution! So simple :)

Comment: Works in Edge, Chrome, Firefox but not IE10/11.

Comment: The `&` is scss, not base css

Comment: Not working in IE 11

Comment: it can be done with using caret-color property.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389261/5749192

Answer (score 8):

I can only say you that you can achieve this by applying the color through css :

```
<input type="text" style="color: transparent;text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;" />
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zD7k/1/)**

Otherwise there is no way to style the text cursor with CSS.

Comment: Not working in IE 11 :(

Comment: @Rakesh Shetty, you've just copied Rafa Romero's answer!