# how to remove blinking cursor in textbox after inserting a word of length 5?

Tags: html, textbox

how to remove blinking cursor after insert a word in the text box. I am using css making the cursor color transparent , but it is not working as expected. is there a way to solve this using java script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the Blinking Cursor from an input type textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515754/how-to-remove-the-blinking-cursor-from-an-input-type-textbox)

Comment: i have tried <input type="text" style="color: transparent">@kumar harsh

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Live demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dnx70aq/)

CSS:

```
.input--textfield {
    border: none;
    color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 ay;
    width: 2em;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="10" class="input--textfield">
```

Comment: actually i want to show in text box ,but when i insert 5 characters it shoulls automatically disappear. is there a solution?@Mardzis

Comment: it same like comment box in here...after i insert something of specific length .the cursor should get hide ?

Comment: nope, bliking cursor should be displayed while typing, but after  typing for specific length , it should get hide...