# How to hide blue cursor in textfield on iphone for extjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-touch

I have got the problem with blue cursor in iPhone. I want to hide that cursor on textbox when i am focusing. Also, i have try on css style but it doesn't work. How I can solve my problem? I am working on sencha extjs. 
**css**

```
.txtPassCodeTransparent input, 
.txtPassCodeTransparent .x-item-disabled input{
  border: 0px !important;
  color: transparent !important;
  cursor: none !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: absolute !important;
  /*font-size: 1px !important;*/

  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent !important;
  -khtml-text-fill-color: transparent !important;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent !important;
  -ms-text-fill-color: transparent !important;
  text-fill-color: transparent !important;

  margin-top: 0.5vh !important;
  height: 10vw !important;
  text-indent: -50%;
  -webkit-text-security: disc;

  &:focus {
    outline: none !important;
  }
}
```

**extjs:**

```
items:[{
  minLength: 6,
  maxLength: 6, 
  xtype:'textcodefield',
  cls: 'txtPassCodeTransparent',
  itemId: 'txtPinCode',
  reference: 'txtPinCode',
  // id: 'pinCode',
  clearIcon: false,
  html: [
    '<span class="passcodeStyleInput"><i class="fa fa-circle backgroundNone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>',
    '<span class="passcodeStyleInput"><i class="fa fa-circle backgroundNone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>',
    '<span class="passcodeStyleInput"><i class="fa fa-circle backgroundNone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>',
    '<span class="passcodeStyleInput"><i class="fa fa-circle backgroundNone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>',
    '<span class="passcodeStyleInput"><i class="fa fa-circle backgroundNone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>',
    '<span class="passcodeStyleInput"><i class="fa fa-circle backgroundNone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>'
    ].join('')
}]
```

moreover, I also have used javascript code but it is not work.

**Here its code**

```
initialize: function(view) {
    view.down('#txtPinCode').el.dom.style.cursor='none';
    view.down('#txtPinCode').el.dom.style.outline='none';
}
```

Comment: Take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor. One of the answers should provide you a solution

Comment: I have tried the solutions in your link above, but it doesn't work with my problem.  [link for image-SDhMU.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDhMU.jpg) Did you have another solution? Anyway thx for your help. @oberbics