# Disabling blinking cursor in Headless Chrome (using puppeteer)

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am capturing screenshots of webpages using the [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) node module.

Some pages have an input field that automatically gets the focus.

I would like the blinking cursor to not appear on the screenshot. Is there an option to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23472096/3708596) in puppeteer using [`addStyleTag`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddstyletagoptions):

```js
const styleContent = `
  input {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;
  }
  input:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

await page.addStyleTag({ content: styleContent });
```

Comment: In my case I needed the text color to stay the same.  So instead I used this css:
```css
* {
  caret-color: transparent !important;
}
```
From https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389261/1408516

Comment: one thing that's obvious, but I was missing at first, make SURE you use `await page.addStyleTag({ content: styleContent });` AFTER you load the page with `await page.goto`.  because of course, the page needs to be loaded, in order to add styles to it! :P

Comment: You can also use `caret-color: transparent !important;`.