# How to remove the Blinker from input box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the blinker inside input. I have seen some websites without the blinker, But I could not find any code related to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't working sir, :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out

```css
.blinker {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 gray;

}
```

```html
<input type="text"   class="blinker">
```

Comment: Clean and simple

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`caret-color: transparent;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color#:%7E:text=The%20caret-color%20CSS%20property,those%20with%20the%20contenteditable%20attribute.) to change the "blinker" to transparent.

```css
input {
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: With a cross browser compatibility of 95.95%, this should be considered the correct answer. Thanveer Shah, I suggest you update your selected answer.

https://caniuse.com/css-caret-color

Comment: @GeorgeVasilopoulos You're right, browser support is better than I thought, there's just no IE or Opera Mini support, but most people these days aren't developing with IE support anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css:

```
input {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 0 #2196f3;

   &:focus {
    outline: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check Lajos Meszaros's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23472096/2929068 those seems like all options you can take to achieve same behavior you are looking for.
>
> > The basic idea is, that the cursor's color is the same as the text's color. So the first thing you do is make the text transparent, thus taking the cursor away with it. Then you can make the text visible again with a text shadow, Use this link to see it live in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx6q1peo)

```css
input[type="text"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline : none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test message" />
```