# How do you remove the blinking caret when clicking on text in a div (not <input>)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm building a fun little Jeopardy *(They reserve all of their rights)* game for my work.

Building it using `grid` is super easy and all, but when I click on the `<div>` it adds the blinking text caret after it (as shown in the picture below).

I tried doing `cursor: default` and `cursor: none` -- none made the `JS` stop functioning, and default didn't do anything (that's what the picture has).

`CSS`

```
#round-one {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px 200px 200px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    gap: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 20px solid black;
}
.round>div,
.round>span {
    background-color: #021489;
    display: inline-grid;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: default;  /** Same Location I tried cursor: none **/
}

.header {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.answer {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #D7A04B;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`HTML` Section

```
<body>
    <div id="round-one" class="round">
        <div id="r1c1r1" class="answer" onclick="question('r1c1r1')">
            100
        </div>
```

and `JS`

```
<script>
    function question(id) {
        alert("test");
    }
</script>
```

I'll deal with the actual `JS` I'll be using later. As it stands right now, the `cursor: default` allows me to click and receive the `alert()`.

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: I do this all the time in my forms by adding `caret-color: transparent;` to the specific inputs ..  Technically it's still "there" .. Just invisible.

Comment: @Zak that worked beautifully - want to throw it in an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide textfield blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `caret-color: transparent;` for my forms where I find the blinking caret distracting.   Technically the caret will still be "there"  Just invisible.